# How to create CGAffineTransform from CGAffineTransformMake?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cgaffinetransform

I went through apple documentation for `CGAffineTransform`. But I couldn't able to figure out what are the values need to be passed to `CGAffineTransformMake` method to create `CGAffineTransform`.

There are six values need to be passed for creation of `CGAffineTransform`. They are a,b,c,d,tx and ty.

Could anyone brief me about the parameters?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Look at the documentation, there is an image describing what parameters go where. If you don't understand that image I would recommend that you read up on the transform matrices

Comment: Do you want us to google for you?

Comment: The values a, b, c, d, tx, ty are just the values of the transformation matrix.

Comment: On the topic of transforms matrices, I though I could shamelessly plug [my blog post "The math behind transforms"](http://ronnqvi.st/the-math-behind-transforms/) ;)

Comment: @Avt : Thanks for reading my question. I don't want you to google for my question. I already did it. But, No one has used CGAffineTransformMake to create CGAffineTransform. To get better understandability, I have asked this question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, unless you understand that matrix manipulations well (or are a masochist), you want to use the `CGAffineTransformMake Rotation / Scale / Translation` methods which provide a much cleaner and obvious interface for the standard tasks you want to complete.

You can also chain the transformations together with `CGAffineTransform Rotate / Scale / Translate` so that you can 'build' a single complex transform (or append to a previous existing transform).